He made an attempt to save the drowning child

He made an attempt to save the drowning child.

'to save the drowing child' is modifying either 'an attempt' or 'made an attempt'?
(i.e. adjectival or adverbial?

Consider that Attempts to save the drowning child failed (as one might hear in a news account) is perfectly idiomatic. And the verb make is nowhere in sight.

But why wouldn't you just say He attempted to save the drowning child? To me, the verbose "marked" version implies a desultory attempt, which is difficult to accept in context.

I don't think it's desultory but "made an attempt" to me suggests a singular action, while "attempted" could mean multiple attempts. If you jump in a river but are immediately swept downstream away from the child, that's "an attempt" and it's not a successful one, but it's not desultory.


He made an attempt to save the drowning child.

Paul's example 'attempts to save the drowning child failed' works, suggesting that the infinitive clause is adjectival.
We test again by shifting the infinitive clause:
To save the drowning child, he made an attempt.
This doesn’t work, further strengthening the assertion that this infinitive clause is adjectival.
As shown in this post, such constructions could sometimes be ambiguous.  More straightforward constructions like what @FumbleFingers said 'He attempted to save the drowning child.' would be clearer.
